# How to mock ATG RqlStatement

Tags: mockito, powermock, atg

Inside my ATG Droplet, I am fetching records from repository. Now when I try to mock `RQLStatement` it throws a `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException`

Below are the statements I am trying to mock:

```
 final RepositoryView view = this.getRepository().getView("product");

 final RqlStatement statement = RqlStatement.parseRqlStatement("id = ?0");

 prodItems = statement.executeQuery(view, params);
```

I used mockito and powermockito but its not working

```
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(RqlStatement.class);

 PowerMockito.when(RqlStatement.parseRqlStatement("id =?0")).thenReturn(this.statementmock);

 Mockito.when(this.statementmock.executeQuery(this.viewMock, params)).thenReturn(new RepositoryItem[4]);
```

Comment: What is the full exception? Also did you add the `@PrepareForTest` annotation?

Comment: ***Don't mock types you don't own***, this can lead to many many problems, some might caught you off guard while in production, still tests where green... Seriously you'd be better off writing integration tests that trying to mock this Oracle subsystem. You should definitely read what internet is saying about that, for example [this article](http://davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html)

Comment: Thanks radimpe  .I forgot adding @PrepareForTest annotation .working for me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding @PrepareForTest annotation .working for me now